# Change the Icon of a Button in a Recycler View in Adapter Class Based off boolean value

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to change the icon of a button in my recycler view every time the activity starts based off a boolean value in my custom object. I assume this has to be done within the adapter since not every groups button will have the same background.

Below is the code for my recycler view adapter:

```
public class RecipeListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<Recipe> mRecipeSet;
    private Button mAddToGroceriesButton;


    public RecipeListAdapter(List<Recipe> recipes){
        mRecipeSet = recipes;
    }

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        //This is what will handle what happens when you click a recipe in the recycler view


        private TextView mRecipeName;
        private TextView mPrepTime;
        private TextView mCookTime;
        private TextView mServingSize;
        private RelativeLayout mRecipeTextSection;


        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mRecipeName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_recycler_view_recipe_name);
            mServingSize = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_recycler_view_serving_size);
            mPrepTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_recycler_view_prep_time);
            mCookTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_recycler_view_cook_time);
            mRecipeTextSection = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.recycled_item_section_view);

            mRecipeTextSection.setOnClickListener(this);

            mAddToGroceriesButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.add_to_grocery_list);
            mAddToGroceriesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    Recipe recipeToGrocery = mRecipeSet.get(position);

                    //RecipeDB dbHelper = new RecipeDB(v.getContext());
                    //dbHelper.addGroceryItem(recipeToGrocery);

                    if(!recipeToGrocery.isInList()) {
                        RecipeDB dbHelper = new RecipeDB(v.getContext());
                        dbHelper.addGroceryItem(recipeToGrocery);

                        recipeToGrocery.setInList(true);
                        dbHelper.updateRecipe(recipeToGrocery);
                        mAddToGroceriesButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_playlist_add_check_black_24dp);
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), recipeToGrocery.getRecipeName() + " added to grocery list.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "That recipe is already in the list.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), RecipeTextView.class);
            Recipe selectedRecipe = mRecipeSet.get(position);
            i.putExtra("view_recipe_key", selectedRecipe);
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }

    }


    public void add(int position, Recipe item) {
        mRecipeSet.add(position, item);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void remove(Recipe item) {
        int position = mRecipeSet.indexOf(item);
        mRecipeSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }



    public RecipeListAdapter(ArrayList<Recipe> myRecipeset) {
        mRecipeSet = myRecipeset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public RecipeListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recipe_item_recycled, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;

    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Recipe recipe = mRecipeSet.get(position);
        String recipeName = recipe.getRecipeName();
        String prepTime = "Prep Time: " + String.valueOf(recipe.getPrepTime()) + " minutes";
        String cookTime = "Cook Time: " + String.valueOf(recipe.getCookTime()) + " minutes";
        String servingSize = "Servings: " + String.valueOf(recipe.getServings());

        holder.mRecipeName.setText(recipeName);

        //Only display values if they are not null
        if(recipe.getServings() != null) {
            holder.mServingSize.setText(servingSize);
        }
        if (recipe.getPrepTime() != null) {
            holder.mPrepTime.setText(prepTime);
        }
        if(recipe.getCookTime() != null) {
            holder.mCookTime.setText(cookTime);
        }


    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(mRecipeSet != null) {
            return mRecipeSet.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }



}
```

I know how to change the background of the button when it's clicked with

```
mAddToGroceriesButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_playlist_add_check_black_24dp);
```

but it's obviously not going to save the state of that button when the activity restarts. I'm just not sure of how to check the boolean value for each group upon activity start up and change the button background accordingly.

I tried using

```
if(recipe.isInList()){
            mAddToGroceriesButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_playlist_add_check_black_24dp);
        }
```

in the onBindViewHolder method but it didn't do anything, and I'm pretty sure that wouldn't be the correct place for it anyways. I know the boolean is working properly since I use it in other places and it works fine.

Here's the relevant XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/recycled_item_section_view"
    android:elevation="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_border"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Recipe name"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/recipe_list_recycler_view_recipe_name"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:maxWidth="275dip"
        android:singleLine="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_below="@id/recipe_list_recycler_view_recipe_name"
        android:id="@+id/recipe_list_recycler_view_serving_size"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_playlist_add_black_24dp"
        android:height="36dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/add_to_grocery_list"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/recipe_list_recycler_view_serving_size"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/recipe_list_recycler_view_prep_time"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/recipe_list_recycler_view_prep_time"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/recipe_list_recycler_view_cook_time"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Recipe class:

```
public class Recipe implements Parcelable {

    //These are all of the qualities a recipe contains, we will create an arraylist of this in the activity
    private String mRecipeName;
    private int mID;
    private String mServings;
    private String mPrepTime;
    private String mCookTime;
    private boolean isInList;

    private List<String> mIngredients;
    private List<String> mDirections;


    public Recipe(){

    }

    public Recipe(int id, String name, String serving, String prep, String cook, List<String>
                  ingredientsList, List<String> directionsList, boolean inList){

        this.mID = id;
        this.mRecipeName = name;
        this.mServings = serving;
        this.mPrepTime = prep;
        this.mCookTime = cook;
        this.mIngredients = ingredientsList;
        this.mDirections = directionsList;
        this.isInList = inList;
    }

    public Recipe(String name, String serving, String prep, String cook, List<String>
            ingredientsList, List<String> directionsList, boolean inList){

        this.mRecipeName = name;
        this.mServings = serving;
        this.mPrepTime = prep;
        this.mCookTime = cook;
        this.mIngredients = ingredientsList;
        this.mDirections = directionsList;
        this.isInList = inList;
    }


    public String getRecipeName() {
        return mRecipeName;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return mID;
    }

    public void setID(int id){
        mID = id;
    }

    public String getServings() {
        return mServings;
    }

    public String getPrepTime() {
        return mPrepTime;
    }


    public void setRecipeName(String recipeName) {
        mRecipeName = recipeName;
    }

    public void setServingSize(String servings) {
        mServings = servings;
    }

    public void setPrepTime(String prepTime) {
        mPrepTime = prepTime;
    }

    public void setServings(String servings) {
        mServings = servings;
    }

    public List<String> getIngredients() {
        return mIngredients;
    }

    public List<String> getDirections() {
        return mDirections;
    }

    public String getCookTime() {
        return mCookTime;
    }

    public void setCookTime(String cookTime) {
        mCookTime = cookTime;
    }

    public void setIngredients(List<String> ingredients) {
        mIngredients = ingredients;
    }

    public void setDirections(List<String> directions) {
        mDirections = directions;
    }

    public boolean isInList() {
        return isInList;
    }

    public void setInList(boolean inList) {
        isInList = inList;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.mRecipeName);
        dest.writeInt(this.mID);
        dest.writeString(this.mServings);
        dest.writeString(this.mPrepTime);
        dest.writeString(this.mCookTime);
        dest.writeByte(this.isInList ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
        dest.writeStringList(this.mIngredients);
        dest.writeStringList(this.mDirections);
    }

    protected Recipe(Parcel in) {
        this.mRecipeName = in.readString();
        this.mID = in.readInt();
        this.mServings = in.readString();
        this.mPrepTime = in.readString();
        this.mCookTime = in.readString();
        this.isInList = in.readByte() != 0;
        this.mIngredients = in.createStringArrayList();
        this.mDirections = in.createStringArrayList();
    }

    public static final Creator<Recipe> CREATOR = new Creator<Recipe>() {
        @Override
        public Recipe createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Recipe(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Recipe[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Recipe[size];
        }
    };
}
```

And main activity class that uses the adapter:

```
public class RecipeList extends AppCompatActivity{
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private int REQUEST_CODE=1;
    private Button mNavigateGroceryButton;
    RecipeDB dbHelper = new RecipeDB(this);
    List<Recipe> recipes;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        recipes = dbHelper.getAllRecipes();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_list);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_recycler_view);


        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new RecipeListAdapter(recipes);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        mNavigateGroceryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.navigate_to_groceries_button_list_view);
        mNavigateGroceryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent i = new Intent(RecipeList.this, ExpandableListViewActivity.class);
                //Log.d("Navigate", "navigate pressed" );
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        //Handles menu buttons
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.recipe_list_add_recipe_actionbar_button:
                //This button creates a new empty Recipe object and passes it to the EditRecipe class
                //The Recipe object is passed as a parcelable
                Recipe passedRecipe = new Recipe();
                Intent i = new Intent(RecipeList.this, EditRecipe.class);
                i.putExtra("passed_recipe_key", (Parcelable) passedRecipe);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
                return true;
            default:
                Log.d("Name,", "default called");
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

    public void addNewReRecipe(Recipe recipe){
        dbHelper.addRecipe(recipe);
        recipes = dbHelper.getAllRecipes();
        mAdapter = new RecipeListAdapter(recipes);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    //Makes the menu bar appear as it is in the action_bar_recipe_list_buttons menu layout file
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_recipe_list_buttons, menu);
        return true;
    }


    //This code is called after creating a new recipe. This is only for creating, and not editing.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Recipe createdRecipe = data.getExtras().getParcelable("recipe_key");
                addNewReRecipe(createdRecipe);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: post your Recipe model class

Comment: Added it as well as my main activity class.

Comment: So what you want to do is save the selection and  display the same when an activity is restarted or the app existed and started again. @knockout1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to declare your button at the top of your ViewHolder with your other views. So move the declaration from the top of your adapter:

`private Button mAddToGroceriesButton;`

Then in your `onBindViewHolder` method you can get a reference to your button through the holder and set the background:

```
if(recipe.isInList()) {
     holder.mAddToGroceriesButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_playlist_add_check_black_24dp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    public class RecipeListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

        private List<Recipe> mRecipeSet;
        private Button mAddToGroceriesButton;


        public RecipeListAdapter(List<Recipe> recipes){
            mRecipeSet = recipes;
        }

        // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
        // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
        // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            //This is what will handle what happens when you click a recipe in the recycler view


            private TextView mRecipeName;
            private TextView mPrepTime;
            private TextView mCookTime;
            private TextView mServingSize;
            private RelativeLayout mRecipeTextSection;


            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                mRecipeName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_recycler_view_recipe_name);
                mServingSize = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_recycler_view_serving_size);
                mPrepTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_recycler_view_prep_time);
                mCookTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list_recycler_view_cook_time);
                mRecipeTextSection = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.recycled_item_section_view);
                mAddToGroceriesButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.add_to_grocery_list);

            }


        }


        public void add(int position, Recipe item) {
            mRecipeSet.add(position, item);
            notifyItemInserted(position);
        }

        public void remove(Recipe item) {
            int position = mRecipeSet.indexOf(item);
            mRecipeSet.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }



        public RecipeListAdapter(ArrayList<Recipe> myRecipeset) {
            mRecipeSet = myRecipeset;
        }

        // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public RecipeListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            // create a new view
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recipe_item_recycled, parent, false);
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;

        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Recipe recipe = mRecipeSet.get(position);
            String recipeName = recipe.getRecipeName();
            String prepTime = "Prep Time: " + String.valueOf(recipe.getPrepTime()) + " minutes";
            String cookTime = "Cook Time: " + String.valueOf(recipe.getCookTime()) + " minutes";
            String servingSize = "Servings: " + String.valueOf(recipe.getServings());

            holder.mRecipeName.setText(recipeName);

            //Only display values if they are not null
            if(recipe.getServings() != null) {
                holder.mServingSize.setText(servingSize);
            }
            if (recipe.getPrepTime() != null) {
                holder.mPrepTime.setText(prepTime);
            }
            if(recipe.getCookTime() != null) {
                holder.mCookTime.setText(cookTime);
            }

            mRecipeTextSection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), RecipeTextView.class);
                Recipe selectedRecipe = mRecipeSet.get(position);
                i.putExtra("view_recipe_key", selectedRecipe);
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            });

            Recipe recipeToGrocery = mRecipeSet.get(position);
            if(!recipeToGrocery.isInList()) {
                        mAddToGroceriesButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_playlist_add_check_black_24dp);
                    }
                    else{
                        mAddToGroceriesButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_playlist_add_check_black_26dp);//set another image
                    }

            mAddToGroceriesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    Recipe recipeToGrocery = mRecipeSet.get(position);

                    //RecipeDB dbHelper = new RecipeDB(v.getContext());
                    //dbHelper.addGroceryItem(recipeToGrocery);

                    if(!recipeToGrocery.isInList()) {
                        RecipeDB dbHelper = new RecipeDB(v.getContext());
                        dbHelper.addGroceryItem(recipeToGrocery);

                        recipeToGrocery.setInList(true);
                        dbHelper.updateRecipe(recipeToGrocery);

                         notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "That recipe is already in the list.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });


        }

        // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            if(mRecipeSet != null) {
                return mRecipeSet.size();
            }
            return 0;
        }



    }
```